# How do you export a comp and not re-render the animation?

Tags: compositing-nodes

Whenever I try to export my animation comp by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>F12</kbd> or *Render > Render Animation*, Blender just renders my scene again rather than exporting my comp.

How do I tell Blender to export my comp, NOT re render the animation? I've tried deleting everything in the scene so there's nothing to render, but then Blender just complains that there's no camera in the scene.

Comment: What is the content of that you call "my comp"?

Comment: If you're asking what's going on in my composite, it's just a single rendered sequence with noise reduction and lens effects. It shouldn't affect my problem.